# on iOS 11 facing error net.fortunal.ical4j.invalid:

Tags: ios, swift3, ekeventkit

On iOS 11, i am using EventKit.
So after adding event and saving it. It works perfectly.

I have added event url in event.

After editing it shows event url has pre adding "net.fortunal.ical4j.invalid:".

So how to resolve this?

Comment: You edit the URL and the server is throwing an error, this has nothing to do with iOS. You are passing parameters that the server does not understand.